# Can drugs be administered through penis?

Tags: human-anatomy, pharmacology

I was reading [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK568677/#:%7E:text=Introduction-,A%20medication%20administration%20route%20is%20often%20classified%20by%20the%20location,drug%27s%20pharmacokinetics%20and%20pharmacodynamic%20profile.) on routes of drug administration and noticed that it mentioned intravaginal drug administration. It looks like this is a good way to take drugs because there are a lot of blood vessels which means you absorb a lot of the drug and you bypass the first-pass metabolism effect which catabolizes a lot of the drug before it gets to your liver.

I noticed there’s no mention of penile drug administration. Would there be any advantage of taking drugs this way, either by insufflation into the urethra or by injection into the penis? I googled it and it sounds like there are no drugs that are administered this way except for penile injections - similar to Botox, but for your penis, and not used for absorption purposes.

Comment: The urethral mucosa is very sensitive (in both males and females) and it would undoubtedly cause significant discomfort - or more - to place and leave medications in it. I can't think of any advantage the urethra would offer when the rectum, which is much less sensitive, is a possibility and a known site (often used for seizures in infants). The paper you linked to is a good one; there are many routes of drug administration available without causing undue pain. Fyi, the first pass effect *is* metabolism by the liver before the drug reaches arterial circulation.

Comment: Just use suppositories.

Comment: there's documented case of weirdos administering recreational drugs in every way possible including the penis, so there are surely documented cases of lsd, opiods, and other drugs going that way.